# How to do Kohana Validation of $_serialize_column inside ORM

Tags: json, validation, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

The validation on Kohana ORM is done using `rules`

```php
function rules()
{
  return array(
    'username' => array(
      array('not_empty'),
      array(array($this, 'availability')),
    )
  );
}
```

I'm struggling to validate a JSON encoded column using `$_serialize_columns`.

```php
class Model_Admin extends ORM {
  protected $_belongs_to = array();
  protected $_has_many = array(
    'plans' => array(),
    'groups' => array(),
    'transactions' => array(),
    'logins' => array()
  );

  protected $_serialize_columns = array('data');

  /**
   * @param array $data
   * @param Validation $validation
   *
   * @return bool
   */
  public function data($data, $validation)
  {
     return 
       Validation::factory(json_decode($data, TRUE))
       // ... rules ...
       ->check();
  }

  public function rules()
  {
     return array(
       'data' => array(
         array(array($this, 'data'), array(':value',':validation')
       )
     );
  }
}
```

the array that gets encoded is:

```
array(
  'name' => '',
  'address' => '',
  'phone' => '',
  'postalcode' => ''
);
```

the `data` method receives the json encoded data, because the ORM runs the filters before doing the validation, so I need to convert it back to an associative array, then create a new validation object to check specifically for the content of that array. Because I can't merge `Validation` rules from another `Validation` instance

Comment: Could you please provide more information on the problem you're experiencing? Are you looking for a way to eliminate the need for a second Validation object?

Comment: yes, I want to know if there's a way to "merge" the serialized column with the existing validation object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

The use of a second validation object is necessary since `save()` causes the internal model validation object to be checked. This means that rules added to the validation object being checked from a validation rule will be ignored (`Validation->check()` imports the rules into local scope before looping).

Since the data itself is technically another object (in the sense of object relationships, it has its own dataset that needs validation) the ideal solution would be to find a way to create a real model that saves the data.

There are numerous other benefits to saving data with proper database column definitions, not least if you need to perform data property lookups, make in-situ changes etc. (which would otherwise require unserializing the data column, potetnailly in all rows).

There are some alternatives, but they feel like kludges to me:

1. Create a model that represents the data object and add rules to it, using `check()` to validate the data (problem: will require a lot of maintenance, no real-world table means columns must be manually defined).
2. Set the data as real columns in the Admin model, and use a filter that will convert it into the data column on set (problem: again, must manually define the columns and exclude the additional columns from the save operation).

I hope this is of some use.

**Original Answer**

The Kohana ORM `save()` method permits the inclusion of an "extra" validation object, which is merged into the main ORM validation object namespace.

This is documented briefly [here](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/validation#external-validation).

If I have understood correctly, I think you are looking to do something like this:

```
// another script, e.g., a controller

// Create the model
$admin = ORM::factory('Admin');

// $data = the data as an array, before serialization ...

$extra_validation = Validation::factory($data)
                    // add ->rule() calls here, but DO NOT chain ->check()
                    ;

// Set $data in the model if it is going to be saved, e.g., $admin->data = $data;
// Set other data... e.g., $admin->foo = 'bar';

// Save the model
try {
    $admin->save($extra_validation);
}
catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
{
    // Manipulate the exception result
}
```

While in this example you must still create another validation object, you are now able to catch all exceptions in a single block. I would recommend using `var_dump()` or similar on `$e->errors()` to check the namespace if you are using i18n messages to provide a human-readable error message. You should find that a namespace called "_external" has been created in the response.

Comment: yes but I want to avoid the code duplication and keep all the necessary validation inside the model, without the need to create the `extra_validation` in the controller

Comment: You could encapsulate the creation of `$extra_validation` inside a model method, e.g., `->data_validation($data);`, which returns the Validation object with rules pertinent to validating the data column. I have updated my answer, unfortunately I can't think of any way to get around the need for a second validation object short of creating another model (which doesn't feel like a good idea if the data isn't going to be saved in its own table).

Comment: the data is saved in his own table, but it's a JSON string, so it can be "flexible" per user

Comment: the only way would be to extend the `save` and `create` methods to automatically include the second validation... I will create a ticket on kohana dev about this